# Find a pattern in a Generic List

Tags: asp.net, regex, list, arraylist, generic-list

I have a Generic List and I'd like to search through the list for items that matches a certain pattern.

For example, if my List contains:

- stand
- Anne
- table
- Stan

and if my pattern is "an", then I need to search through the list for any item that contains "an" in the text, regardless of case. In this case, it'll return: stand, Anne, and Stan.

This is what I have so far (where TextBox1 contains the pattern):

```
string str = array1.Find(item => item == TextBox1.Text.Trim());

if (str != "")
{
    Label3.Text = "List Item Found";
}
else
{
    Label3.Text = "List Item Not Found.";
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use LINQ:

```
var matches = array1.Where(x => x.Contains(TextBox1.Text.Trim())).ToList();
```

To make it case-insensitive, use `IndexOf`:

```
var matches = array1.Where(x => x.IndexOf(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look - does this method work with different cases (i.e. upper or lower) of the text?

Comment: No, `Contains` is case-sensitive. I've updated my answer with case-insensitive solution.

Comment: Thanks so much...it's saying 'local variable x cannot be declared' when I try to run. Am i missing something?

Comment: OK, what's the exact message?

Comment: A local variable named 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'x', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: Ahhhhhh ooops sorry i had something above the code using x ><

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47376/discussion-between-marcinjuraszek-and-viv-acious)

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new RegEx("an", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var anyMatches = array1.Any(x => regex.IsMatch(x));
if(anyMatches)
{
    Label3.Text = "List Item Found";
}
else
{
    Label3.Text = "List Item Not Found";
}
```

Comment: depending on the size you might want to use a Compiled RegEx.

Comment: Thanks so much @Aron. I will take a look at this method. Is it case sensitive?

Comment: depends on your regex. See [RegexOptions.IgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)